# How to convert JSP written in Eclipse on Windows to Linux?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, jsp

I wrote JSP program with Eclipse and trying to convert that from a windows machine to a Linux machine. The problem that I am facing is Eclipse uses packages to store files those packages are then included into different files, on top of that Eclipse uses XML files to load JSP files. If I want my program to run on Linux how do I go about converting includes of packages and XML to something Linux can recognize?

Edit: I have to run this on a Linux server that doesn't have Eclipse, and I am not allowed to install it.

Comment: Have you tried just opening your project in Eclipse on a Linux system?

Comment: @Wayzard Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have to run this program on a Linux server that doesn't have Eclipse, I'll make the edit to reflect that.

Comment: Then it sounds like your question is really about how to export your application so it can be deployed to a web container outside of Eclipse.  Unless your application uses JNI or platform-specific libraries, you probably don't have to do anything special to make it work on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the operating system. You just need to install a servlet container like Tomcat on your Linux server and deploy your application as a war file.

Comment: I have installed Tomcat7 but the problem I'm running into is that the browser is trying to save .java files and not run them. Is there a way to tell the browser to run the servlet and not save it? And what do you mean by a war file?

Comment: You can't run *.java files. You have to compile them first. Have you exported your dynamic web project as *.war file? If yes, you shouldn't see *.java files at all.

Comment: no I just copied the files to Linux, so I see my mistake, thanks.